# How could I write expression like map (-3) [1..10] in haskell?

Tags: haskell

It seems that `(-3)` is treated as a negative number instead of a curried function in haskell.

if I write

```
map (+3) [1..3]
```

I get `[4,5,6]`

However, `map (-3) [1..3]` would cause an error.

So, How could I map `(-)` to a list elegantly instead of having to use `map (\x->x-3) xs`?

Comment: map (subtract 3) [1..10]

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
map (flip (-) 3) [1..3]

-- or the other way around
map (3 -) [1..3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this:

```
map (-3 +) [1..3]
```